# Is there to view simulink XY graph during the simulation?

Tags: animation, graph, real-time, simulink, joystick

I am trying to visualize the input I am getting from a joystick on a simple XY Graph in Simulink. I can display the values of the various axes easily using the Scope. However I want to display the X and Y values from the joystick as a dot moving around in real time on a graph or animation or whatever. If there is a better / easier way to do this, maybe with something else then Simulink, then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the `XY Graph` block serves your purpose. You can see the documentation in the following link :
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/plot-circle-with-xy-graph.html

You can also refer the following if you could log the signals in `Simulation Data Inspector`:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/visualize-simulation-data-on-an-xy-plot.html

All the best!